# Filtering blocks on basis of transaction logs in web3j

Tags: events, web3j, logs, filters

I want to filter blocks on the basis of a log present inside transactions. How can I do that?
I don't have any contract address and want to filter all the blocks generated by all the contracts.

```
        EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST,
            DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,contractAddress);
```

I want to remove `contractAddress` from this filter.